# How do I resize an armature without ruining its poses?

Tags: rigging, armature

I have an armature that I need to resize. When I scale it and apply the scale changes, all of the armature's associated poses/animations are ruined, because the position data for bones in the poses wasn't scaled with it. The way I understand it, poses work by storing data about a bone relative to the "rest pose" position of the bone's parent. It's *this* position data that doesn't change when the armature's size is changed, resulting in the pose being rendered unusable. If I scale the armature and *don't apply* the scale changes, everything works correctly; the armature is uniformly resized and all the poses/animations are preserved. But as soon as I *control + a* and apply the new scale, I end up with a crushed mess.

The armature, posed:
[image: The armature]

The armature, after having been scaled, but without the scale applied:
[image: The armature, after having been scaled]

After applying the scale:
[image: After applying the scale]

Is there some way to make the pose data scale *along with* the armature (so that when a size change would be applied nothing would appear to change)? It seems like a very important thing, and that there should be some sort of *"scale poses with armatures"* option.

**TL;DR:** How do you scale an armature ***along with*** its associated poses/animations?

Comment: Parent everything to an empty. Scale the empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to scale the pose data's F-curves (you don't need to scale the armature and apply the scale then..):

1. You need to have keys for scale and location for every bone
2. Hide rotation f-curves for every bone (don't want to alter rotations)
3. Set pivot to 2D Cursor and position the cursor so the Y is 0 and X is any frame:

   [image]
4. Select all visible (<kbd>A</kbd>). <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to scale animations/poses in pose space. Tadaa!

Comment: What if you have various animation?

Comment: @DouglasRosa Then you do this for all animations F-curves or you write a script that does it for all if there are too many. A hint how to do it is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/modifying-fcurve-values-on-armature-bones-via-python

Answer (score 0):

It works for the simple cube but I found out how to do it to the armature with mesh connected, because sometimes stuff like this simply happens.

[image]

When you just scale it and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

I accidentally found that if you scale it and instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> use *Scale to Deltas* it works just fine.

[image]

My goal was to change dimensions from `Z=3.45` to `Z=2.00` without changing `111` scale proportion. And it works just fine.

My blender version is 4.01.