# Edit armature with existing animations

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, edit-mode, pose-mode

As far as I know, this is not possible, but I just want to be sure there's no way before discarding the idea completely.

So, I have a character rig that's animated, and I want to use it with another model of a character with a different build and I need to adjust some bones in edit mode. After doing this I tried to reset the bones in pose mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, but none worked. I tried to apply the pose, yet that didn't work either; the bones didn't change size. It looks as it should when I'm in *Pose Mode* and have it set it to *Rest Pose*, but then I can't animate it.

Does anyone know if there's a way?

Comment: Shady Puck, thanks for the edit, it probably does make the idea clearer for some people and I appreciate it. But to be honest I feel like if the idea was understandable from the start then there's no need for someone to modify it and take away the personal touch of someone's writing, this is not an essay and does not need perfect grammar and formalism. So, even though I appreciate it and thank you, I think your edits would be better if they just fix what needs to be fixed instead of changing the original poster's personal way of writing and expressing themselves too.

Comment: You want the rig to appear in edit mode like it does in rest pose?

Comment: It already does that, rest pose bones = edit mode bones. I want the normal pose, animatable and keyframeable one, to look like the rest pose or edit mode.

Comment: Perhaps an image or too, or even a test file would shed some light on this.  Is there any IK on the rig? Are you linking the old action to the new rig??  Remove action and apply location, rotation and scale (effectively set all to zero) and rig should match between rest-pose and pose mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing armature with existing animations is totally possible.

When you edit the armature in edit-mode, you directly change the rest-position. Any transformation (animation) is relative to this rest-position, so by changing the rest-pose you might break the animation (but if the animation is mostly rotations and you change only proportions of bones there should be no problem)

The rest-position is identical to pose-position without any transformations or **constraints**. This is by definition, so when you <kbd>Alt + G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt + R</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt + S</kbd>, and you turn off all constraints you **must** get the rest-position.

You can also apply any pose as a rest-position by Pose > Apply > Apply Pose As Rest Pose. How to do that with already binded mesh is here: [Can I set my pose position like the new rest position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49768/can-i-set-my-pose-position-like-the-new-rest-position/49804#49804)

Any animation can be also edited so it is not ruined:
[How do I resize an armature without ruining its poses?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24839/how-do-i-resize-an-armature-without-ruining-its-poses/24856#24856)

Comment: Ok, I don't know what was going on before because I tried like 3 different times restarting the file and trying different approaches, but now when I was recording (following the exact same process I did the last time) it worked... The solution you gave is the same thing I was doing from the beginning and that I explained in the question, but for some unkown reason didn't work before and it did now. Guess it's one of those things that only work when somebody else is gonna watch.

Comment: Uploaded the recording just in case someone wants to see it or something... https://youtu.be/xLuL4ZJ90rs