# Modifying FCurve values on armature bones via python

Tags: python, fcurves

I have this script, which does what i need with object actions.

```
import bpy

y_scale = 10

try:
    for fcu in bpy.context.object.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        if fcu.data_path == "location":
            for kp in fcu.keyframe_points:
                kp.co.y *= y_scale
                kp.handle_left.y *= y_scale
                kp.handle_right.y *= y_scale
except TypeError:
    pass
```

But i actually need to do this with armature bones. Can somebody modify this script to make it work with bones on all actions presented in armature?

Comment: `if fcu.data_path.endswith("location"):` would prob do it.  The location data path for pose bones is `pose.bones["Bone"].location` for example with bone name: "Bone".

Comment: It works now, thank you. How do i mark this answered?

Comment: Noting that the modified script is still viable in 2.8, and quickly fixes broken actions and pose libraries after applying an armature's scale. Great work!