# Skeleton mirror breaks when applied

Tags: python, rigging, armature, fcurves

I downloaded the *Unarmed Equip Torch 01* animation (skeleton only) from [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&query=equip%20torch) and wanted to mirror it so the torch was in the right hand (and then I noticed you can mirror it right in the web, but let's ignore that).

I imported the FBX in Blender 2.92 (same behavior in 2.91), everything was fine. After **applying** a -1 X scale (I set the xyz scale to 1 from 0.01 first, no problem there), the animation broke. In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24839/how-do-i-resize-an-armature-without-ruining-its-poses?rq=1) the accepted answer says I should scale the pose data's f-curves instead and points to this [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65020/modifying-fcurve-values-on-armature-bones-via-python?newreg=4491b6ba7c2f435294fb735fc25ac2c2) for a Python script to do so.

I tried this version:

```
import bpy

scale = -1
i = 0

try:
    for fcu in bpy.context.object.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        if fcu.data_path.endswith("location") or fcu.data_path.endswith("scale"):
            # 3 means X coordinates.
            if i % 3 == 0:
                for kp in fcu.keyframe_points:
                    kp.co.y *= scale
                    kp.handle_left.y *= scale
                    kp.handle_right.y *= scale
            i += 1
except TypeError:
    pass
```

But it doesn't work. I'm pretty new to Blender, so I'm not sure what's going on. I tried running the script both before and after applying the scale, what am I missing?

Thanks!